# OCI_CONNECT, Connecting to remote machine's TNS

Tags: php, oracle, tns

Apache web server is running in my machine (localhost). But TNS entry is located in another machine within same network,

another machine ip is - 192.168.11.122.

I need to connect remote machine's TNS as follows. but givin an error

> Fatal error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

```
oci_connect("ABS", "b2a8a621", "//192.168.11.122 / 10.20.42.11:1521/AVABS");
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is 10.20.42.11 the IP address of the Oracle Database Server? If so, try:

```
oci_connect("ABS", "b2a8a621", "//10.20.42.11:1521/AVABS");
```